# How to pack switchyard application with maven

Tags: java, maven, switchyard

How can I pack switchyard application with has dependencies to my another project with Maven? Currently I'm trying to make things work as explained here
[official dock](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/SWITCHYARD/Deployment).

But with no result, on startup of application in log file I see

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aspiderngi/common/switchyard/InventoryRequest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aspiderngi.common.switchyard.InventoryRequest from...
```

Is it possible to achieve anyways?

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.switchyard</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>com.example.switchyard:sy-example</name>
    <artifactId>sy-example</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <switchyard.version>2.0.0.Final</switchyard.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
                <artifactId>switchyard-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspiderngi</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifacts-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-camel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-camel-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-transform</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-validate</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-test-mixin-cdi</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-bean</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
                <artifactId>switchyard-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannerClassNames>
                        <param>org.switchyard.transform.config.model.TransformSwitchYardScanner</param>
                    </scannerClassNames>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/lib/*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/switchyard.xml
                    </packagingExcludes>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>target/classes/META-INF</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>switchyard.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: pleaso show us your `pom.xml`

Comment: i've updated question with pom

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven Shade plugin:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
              <shadedClassifierName>jackofall</shadedClassifierName> <!--     Any name that makes sense -->
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: can you be more exact? do i need to use other plugins like war-plugin or switchyard-plugin?

Comment: when i run mvn package i get war file that i cannot deploy nor unzip.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out. The dependent project must have its own pom.xml(child)
Include this child pom to the parent pom. And include the below code in the parent pom.xml 
This would directly deploy the application in the server
From project root in cmd execute the below commands:
1. mvn clean 
2. mvn dependency:resolve
3. mvn install

if you are using Eclipse, use maven update. then Run As maven install

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
                <artifactId>switchyard-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannerClassNames>
                        <param>org.switchyard.transform.config.model.TransformSwitchYardScanner</param>
                    </scannerClassNames>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>

                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

if you are using Bean then include

```
<scannerClassNames>
          <param>org.switchyard.transform.config.model.BeanSwitchYardScanner</param>
    </scannerClassNames>
```